# How to run .profile inside a shell script in ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am running a script which is echoing the environment variables in .profile file and than I am running the script, but I am getting following error

I tried following:

```
node@node-virtual-machine:~$ cat env.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/home/node/jdk1.6.0_45' >> /home/node/.profile
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin' >> /home/node/.profile
cd /home/node/
source .profile
node@node-virtual-machine:~$ sh env.sh 
sudo: source: command not found
```

How to execute .profile within a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
sh env.sh
```

You should run:

```
bash ./env.sh
```

Besides instead of:

```
source .profile
```

use:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: Your solution does not gives me error, but the changes are not getting reflected after running the script

Comment: environment variables are not getting set :(

Comment: But your shown script isn't setting/printing any env variables? If you print value right after `source ~/.profile` you will see all the values from `~/.profile`

Comment: @Prats: can you please show how source ~/.profile worked in scripts itself? I am in a similar situation and stuck!!

Answer (score 0):

If `.profile` exists as `/home/node/.profile`, you have all that is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your script says `/bin/bash` at the top but you run it with `sh` which is probably `dash` on your system.  You probably are already running Bash at the prompt, so you should say `source env.sh` instead of `sh env.sh` if you want the variables to be exposed to your terminal.