# How to source my .profile file and make it change the current shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am running an init bash script and at the end of it I want to source my `.profile` script which in turn sources my `.bashrc` file.

For some reason the `.profile` is sourced (I can tell because it prints out a statement) but the rest of my init script is not run

I have looked at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22913551/how-to-run-profile-inside-a-shell-script-in-ubuntu) two [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274397/reload-profile-in-bash-shell-script-in-unix) both of which say to use `source ~/.profile` which is what I am doing (except with a full path instead of `a`) but it is still not working.  Am I doing something wrong?

The end of my init script looks like:

```
source "$USERDIR/.profile"
# This should be done from .profile but it is presently not working correctly
# Nothing below gets executed
source "$USERDIR/.bashrc"
cd $USERDIR
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you running the "init" script?  You need to __source__ it or else all the changes will be lost when the script exits.

Comment: @John1024  I have just been running it through ./init.sh  I would use `source` but I need this to be run as `sudo` (because of what is inside) and `sudo source` doesn't work...

Comment: OK.  Just use sudo inside the script and only for the commands that actually need sudo.

Comment: It must be noted that sudo prevents inheritance of env variables except what is allowed in `sudoers` or when option `-E` is used. So a `source .profile` followed by `sudo command` is not guaranteed that `sudo` will inherit the env from `.profile`. Try `sudo -E command` in your script.

Comment: Put a `set -x` before the `source "$USERDIR/.profile"` and you'll see exactly what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to execute:

```
source ~/.profile
```

as `root` user or with `sudo`.

Alternatively you can try to add `sudo -E` before commands that actually need `sudo`.

[Linux man page:](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)

> **-E** The **-E** (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables. The security policy may return an error if the **-E** option is specified and the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

[Linux and UNIX Man Pages:](https://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/8/sudo/)

> The **-E** (preserve environment) option will override the env_reset option in [sudoers(5)](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/5/sudoers/).  It is only available when either the matching command has the SETENV tag or the setenv option is set in [sudoers(5)](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/5/sudoers/).